# How to add bulk hardware access in softlayer using API and nodejs

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have below code to add bulk hardware access in softlayer using API and nodejs:

```
slClient
    .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
    .path('User_Customer', userID, 'addBulkHardwareAccess',{"hardwareIds":["XXXXX,XXXXXXX"]})
    .post()
    .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });   
};
```

But it gives error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is parameters() method to provide parameters.

```
slClient
    .auth(slUserID, slApiKey)
    .path('User_Customer', args.userID, 'addBulkHardwareAccess')
    .parameters([[XXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXX]])
    .post()
    .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

Comment: I have noticed one thing this function sometimes adds hardware and sometimes reduces existing hardware count for  a ID.   What could be issue here?

Answer (score 1):

To add bulk hardware access, use the following rest api:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userCustomerId]/addBulkHardwareAccess
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters":[
    [
            111111,
            222222,
            333333,
            444444  
    ]
  ]
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addBulkHardwareAccess/

Or if you want to add access to all hardware, use this rest api:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userCustomerId]/addPortalPermission
```

Body: Json

```
{

"parameters": [
                 {
                     "keyName": "ACCESS_ALL_HARDWARE"                             
                 }                                                                                                                                         
            ] 
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/addPortalPermission/

Comment: I want to use nodejs path() method to achieve this. But I am not sure how to pass parameters(array of device IDs.)